# Save response ID from Sendgrid to spring boot db

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, sendgrid, sendmail

I am using the Sendgrid mail template for sending mail, and it is working completely fine. Mail is sent properly to recipients with the proper body. Now I came with a new requirement, which is, By using SendGrid it provides you with a transaction ID of each mail you sent. Now I have to save it in my DB. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a mail with the SendGrid API the response is empty, so you don't get an ID back.

However, what you can do is set anything you like in the `custom_args` for either the entire request or for each personalisation. `custom_args` are sent back in the parameters for every [tracking event](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event). So, you can generate your own ID and store that, then when you receive an event from the API, you will get that ID as the `custom_args` and can attribute the event to the original email.

I wrote a blog post about [how to do this in Ruby on Rails](https://www.twilio.com/blog/track-email-status-ruby-on-rails-sendgrid), but I don't have an example in Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I had resolved it by saving the X-message-id provided by SendGrid.

Comment: Oh cool. Can you add that as an answer as well then? That way other people who have the same problem will know how you did it.